# Shout out from the American English

Tags: meaning, slang

From the `Coach Carter` movie:

> — That reminds me, Mr. Battle. Mr. Gesek tells me he doesn't see you
>   in his classroom very often.
>
> — Yeah, we cool, though, me and him. Mr. Gesek is a big basketball
>   fan.
>
> — Well, as of now, you're suspended. Oh, you can practice, but you
>   can't play until Mr. Gesek tells me you're caught up in his class. And
>   that's a ***shout out*** to the rest of you.

That was said while the coach was chastising the basketball team for bad academical. I was confused by the phrase `shout out`. The [dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shout+out) tells that it means to speak loudly. But that was said in a very calm way and couch didn't speak loud actually. So what does that mean?

Comment: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/shout-out_2 and http://de.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=shout-out. Use in this case: a warning.

Comment: @Stephie Is that a slang expression? Can I use it in more-or-less formal speech?

Comment: It's African American Vernacular English (although it exists also in mainstream)

Comment: Not really slang, more colloquial. Use primarily in spoken language, not as much in written form. But unless you are in a super formal setting, you can express thanks by saying: "I'd like to give a shout-out to all our volunteers who helped us build this ...." (just a random example).

Comment: [Those two](http://www.stuffyoushouldknow.com/about/) (neither of them African American, @TRomano) will quite often start or end their [podcast](http://www.stuffyoushouldknow.com/podcasts/) with a shout-out either to a listener or some sponsor. Side note, clearly off-topic: I *really* like and recommend this podcast.

Comment: @TRomano So you've never used such phrase in your speech, huh?

Comment: "Shout out" as a slang term has been around for a long time in mainstream American English. For example, you might hear a radio DJ say something like *We'd like to give a big shout out to our listeners in Springfield.*, where "give a shout out" could mean "say hello and thanks to" or "(gratefully) acknowledge".  But in AAVE usage, one often hears "shout out to...".  In AAVE, "give a" or "here's a" are not part of the collocation. https://www.google.com/search?q=AAVE+shout+out&oq=AAVE+s&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i61.1817j0j8&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Comment: This looks like it might be an interesting book: https://books.google.com/books?id=mtqrQIzIM4wC&pg=PA130&lpg=PA130&dq=AAVE+shout+out&source=bl&ots=bFzQluv7p0&sig=tQ5dw0mOZA0DllIxallgbjOugCo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=b49QVcXUJZPmsASiyIGoAQ&ved=0CHAQ6AEwDw#v=onepage&q=AAVE%20shout%20out&f=false

Comment: Mainstream attestation of "give a big shout out to": https://www.google.com/search?q=%22give%20a%20big%20shout%20out%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: I think in this example, they're pushing the standard definition of 'announcement' all the way to 'warning'.

Answer (score 3):

"To give a shout out to X" means *to give credit to X* or *to mention X in an positive announcement*

I haven't seen the movie this is from, but it looks like the term in the question's excerpt is being used intentionally against the above meaning as a sarcastic effect.

I remember first hearing this on rap radio stations in the early 90's, but everyone says it now.